# Vertical align between to absolute positioned elements

Tags: html, css

I am trying to align two elements which are absoluted positioned relative to a container element, and I fail to see why when applying the same top value, one of the elements (the ul) goes a little bit more down.  You can see it live [here](http://jsfiddle.net/BbYuM/)

I have the following HTML:

```
<div id="header">
    <div class="inner">
        <span id="logo_description"> Description comes here </span>
        <ul id="user_menu">
            <strong>name</strong> | 
            <a href="#"> Account </a> |
            Language
            <select> 
                <option> Option1 </option>
                <option> Option2 </option>
            </select>                
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the following CSS:

```
#header {
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    padding: 8px 0 13px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 51px;
}

#header .inner {
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 1000px;
}

#header .inner #logo_description {
    position:absolute;
    top:20px;
}

#header #user_menu {
    display: inline;
    font-size: 12px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    top: 20px;
    text-align: right;
}​
```

​

Answer (score 1):

it is possible that your browser is adding extra padding to the ul element.
mozilla is infamous for this.

inspect the element to check for padding.

this will remove default padding from chrome, for example.

```
-webkit-padding-start:0px;
```